# how to hide and appear two div in a component using the boolean value from another component in angular

Tags: angular, event-handling, observable, decorator

Thanks in advance. I'm setting up a Crud operation for two different parameters, say Rules and Rule Parameter. Here both components have similar CRUD operations components(rule-add-model.component.ts & its html), to avoid the repetition of these CRUD components I generated the boolean value isRowParam (rule-grid.component.ts and its html). the aim is how can i pass this boolean value to another component say rule-add-model.component.ts and its html which contains two divs.

Here  contains the CRUD operation buttons, which emits the CRUD's.

## rule-grid.component.html

```
<app-grid-header (ActionClickedEvent)="onActionClicked($event)"></app-grid-header>
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center" >
<div style="background-color: teal;">
<kendo-grid [data]="records"
            [pageSize]="state.take"
            [skip]="state.skip"
            [sort]="state.sort"
            [sortable]="true"
            [pageable]="true"
            [scrollable]="'scrollable'"
            [groupable]="false"
            [group]="state.group"
            [filterable]="true"
            [filter]="state.filter"
            (dataStateChange)="dataStateChange($event)"
            [selectable]="true"
            (selectionChange)="gridUserSelectionChange(gridUser, $event)"
            [height]="500"
            [style.maxWidth.px]="1300"
            (cellClick)="onCellClick($event)"
            (dblclick)="onDblClick()"
            >
            <kendo-grid-column field=name title="Name"[width]="300"></kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column field=type title="Rule Type" filter="numeric" [width]="250"></kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column field=programName title="Program Name" ></kendo-grid-column>
           </kendo-grid>
        </div>

        <div style="background-color: teal" *ngIf="isRowParam">
            <kendo-grid [data]="record_RuleParms"
                        [pageSize]="state.take"
                        [skip]="state.skip"
                        [sort]="state.sort"
                        [sortable]="true"
                        [pageable]="true"
                        [scrollable]="'scrollable'"
                        [groupable]="false"
                        [group]="state.group"
                        [filterable]="true"
                        [filter]="state.filter"
                        (dataStateChange)="dataStateChange($event)"
                        [selectable]="true"
                        (selectionChange)="gridUserSelectionChange(gridUser, $event)"
                        [height]="500"
                        (dblclick)="onDblClick_Param()"
                        >
                        <kendo-grid-column field=name title="Name"[width]="300"></kendo-grid-column>
                        <kendo-grid-column field=defaultValue title="Default Value" filter="numeric" [width]="250"></kendo-grid-column>
                        <kendo-grid-column field=dataType title="Data Type" ></kendo-grid-column>
                       </kendo-grid>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

## rule-grid.component.ts

```
 export class RuleGridComponent{
    

    private apiUrl: string = 'api/Rules';
    private selectedData: any;
    public records: GridDataResult;
    datas: any ;
    
    public clickedRowItem;
    public isRowParam=false;

    private apiUrlRuleParams: string='api/RuleParameters'
    public record_RuleParms:GridDataResult;
    
    private state: DataSourceRequestState = {
      skip: 0,
      take: 10
    };
    public grid: GridComponent;
    constructor(private ruleService: RulesService,private dataService: GridDataService, private dialog: MatDialog,private ngZone: NgZone,private excelService:ExcelService ) { }

   ngOnInit() {   
     this.dataService.fetch(this.state,this.apiUrl).subscribe(r => this.records = r);
  }
  
public dataStateChange(state: DataStateChangeEvent): void {
  this.state = state;
  this.dataService.fetch(state,this.apiUrl)
    .subscribe(r => this.records = r);

    this.fitColumns();
}

public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.fitColumns();
}

private fitColumns(): void {
    this.ngZone.onStable.asObservable().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(() => {
    this.grid.autoFitColumns();
  });
}
 gridUserSelectionChange(gridUser, selection) {
  // let selectedData = gridUser.data.data[selection.index];
  const selectedData = selection.selectedRows[0].dataItem;
  console.log(selectedData);
  this.selectedData = selectedData;
}




//----------------------------------- Rule Type Grid --------------------------------------------- Boolean generates here  in onDblClick(e)----//
onCellClick(e) {
  this.clickedRowItem = e.dataItem;  
}

onDblClick(e) {
  console.log('Double click, data item: ', this.clickedRowItem);
  if(this.clickedRowItem!=null){
    this.isRowParam=true;
  
    this.dataService.fetch(this.state,this.apiUrlRuleParams+"/"+this.clickedRowItem.id)
    .subscribe((r :any)=> {
                    this.record_RuleParms = r.data;
                    console.log(this.record_RuleParms);
                  }
    )
  }
}
```

## rule.add-model.ts

```
<div style="border-radius: .2em;border-color: teal" *ngIf="!isRowParam">
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center" style="padding:1em;background-color: teal;color:white;">
        <h3>Add New Rule</h3>
    </div>
    <mat-divider class="mat-divider-custom" ></mat-divider>
    <form [formGroup]="ruleAddFormGroup" autocomplete="off" >
        <div fxLayout="column">
        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
            <div fxFlex="64" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100">
                    <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
                    <input autocomplete="off" maxlength="100" matInput placeholder="Enter Name" formControlName="name"
                        type="text">
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
            <div fxFlex="64" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
               <!-- <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100" style="min-width:100%">
                    <mat-label>Rule Type</mat-label>
                    <input autocomplete="off" maxlength="100" matInput placeholder="Enter Rule Type" formControlName="type"
                        type="text">
                </mat-form-field> -->
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100">
                    <mat-label>Type</mat-label>
                    <mat-select disableOptionCentering="true" placeholder="Select the Rule Type" formControlName="type"
                        [(ngModel)]="ruletypes" >
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let t of actionType" [value]="t">
                            {{t.type}}
                        </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
            <div fxFlex="64" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100" style="min-width:100%">
                    <mat-label>Program Name</mat-label>
                    <input autocomplete="off" maxlength="100" matInput placeholder="Enter Program Name" formControlName="programName"
                        type="text">
                </mat-form-field>
            </div> 
         </div>       
        </div>
           
        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end">
            <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="onClose()">Cancel</button>
            <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onAdd()">Add</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>



    <div style="border-radius: .2em;border-color: teal" *ngIf="isRowParam">
        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center" style="padding:1em;background-color: teal;color:white;">
            <h3>Add New Rule Parameter</h3>
        </div>
        <mat-divider class="mat-divider-custom" ></mat-divider>
        <form [formGroup]="ruleAddFormGroup" autocomplete="off" >
            <div fxLayout="column">
            <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
                <div fxFlex="64" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100">
                        <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
                        <input autocomplete="off" maxlength="100" matInput placeholder="Enter Name" formControlName="name"
                            type="text">
                    </mat-form-field>
                </div>
                <div fxFlex="64" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
                   <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100" style="min-width:100%">
                        <mat-label>Default Value</mat-label>
                        <input autocomplete="off" maxlength="100" matInput placeholder="Enter Default Value" formControlName="defaultValue"
                            type="text">
                    </mat-form-field>
                 
                </div>
                <div fxFlex="64" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100" style="min-width:100%">
                        <mat-label>Program Name</mat-label>
                        <input autocomplete="off" maxlength="100" matInput placeholder="Enter DataType" formControlName="sataType"
                            type="text">
                    </mat-form-field>
                </div> 
             </div>       
            </div>
               
            <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end">
                <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="onClose()">Cancel</button>
                <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onAdd()">Add</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
```

## rule-add-model.component.ts

```
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Component, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
import { RulesService } from 'src/api/services';
import { SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { getTreeNoValidDataSourceError } from '@angular/cdk/tree';
import { filter, debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-rule-add-model',
    templateUrl: './rule-add-model.component.html',
    //styleUrls: ['./rule-add-model.component.scss']
})
export class RuleAddComponent {
    ruleTypesService: RulesService;
    ruleAddFormGroup: FormGroup;
    onAddComplete: any = new EventEmitter<any>();
    onAddError: any = new EventEmitter<any>();
    onEdit = new EventEmitter();
    imageObj: SafeResourceUrl = '';
    ruletypes:string[];
    actionType:any;
  
     

    constructor(
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<RuleAddComponent>,
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private ruleService: RulesService) {
        this.dialogRef.disableClose = true;
        this.ruleAddFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
            name: ['', [Validators.required]],
            type:['1', [Validators.required]],
            programName:['', [Validators.required]],            
        });
        
        this.ruletypes =this.getRuleTypes();
      //  this.actionType=this.ruletypes;
  
    }
// Basic format to handle the Subscribe delay : NOTE: always add console.log() after the binding of datum.
    getRuleTypes():any{
           this.ruleService.GetRule().subscribe((res:any) => {
           this.actionType=res.data;
           this.ruletypes=res.data[0];
           console.log(res.data);          
        }
        )
    }

    onClose(): void {
        this.dialogRef.close();
    }

    onAdd() {
        if (this.ruleAddFormGroup.valid) {
            const rule = this.ruleAddFormGroup.value;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(rule));
            const data = {
                name: rule.name,
                type:rule.type["type"],
                programName:rule.programName               
            };
            debugger;
            this.ruleService.PostRule(data).subscribe(res => {
                debugger;
                if (res) {
                    this.onAddComplete.next(data);
                    this.dialogRef.close();
                }
            }, err => {
                this.onAddError.next(err.error);
                this.dialogRef.close();
            });

        } else {
            this.validateAllFormFields(this.ruleAddFormGroup);
        }
    }

   

 
    validateAllFormFields(formGroup: FormGroup) {
        Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach(field => {
            const control = formGroup.get(field);
            if (control instanceof FormControl) {
                control.markAsTouched({ onlySelf: true });
            } else if (control instanceof FormGroup) {
                this.validateAllFormFields(control);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: so you want to pass the data between two components?

Comment: yes, in rule-add-model.ts , *ngIf="isRowParam" (which is not correct here). based upon the isRowParam i need to control all other operations.

Comment: then try to create a service which is used to communicate between components

Comment: use services.And instead of posting the code you can make a stackblitz project.Its better for us to understand the code better.

Comment: what service? like this example.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46664929/how-to-change-the-values-of-boolean-in-between-two-components-in-angular-4

Comment: @tufonas working on it but got another error, which is not this domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either you can use service or you can use @input @output so you can pass data between two components.
by default you can set isRowParam false and after whatever the other component Boolean value do isRowParam  true. so div can hide and appear.